# how to mute all apps while my app is running?

Tags: mute

I'm working on an app that generate sounds through audio jack to be transmitted through micro-controller to RC car, and move it right, left, forward, and back.
But the problem is the sounds of notifications interrupt the app and sends wrong data to the toy"RC Car", so I need to know how I can mute all apps while my app is running??

Comment: Hi! Are you asking for a programmatic solution or an end-user based solution? Former is off topic here. Please visit our [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Turn off notification and ringtone sound?